# Makefile with command line arguments

Tags: c, makefile

I have a program called main.c and one header called functions.h. Main has the need for command line arguments, and I don't know how to build the makefile so it will accept the cmd line arguments.

```
main.c:
#include <functions.h>
int main(char agrv[], int argc){.....}

makefile:
p1: main.o insertNode.o functions.h
     gcc -c main.o insertNode.o -p1
main.o: main.c
     gcc -c main.c
insertNode.o: insertNode.c
     gcc -c insertNode.c
```

I need to type into the command line "p1 inputfile.txt outputfile.txt" and I can't figure it out

Comment: makefiles have no bering on that.

Comment: You pass those arguments to the compiled program, not to `make`. But it looks like your `Makefile` is not creating a program (it's just compiling sources into object files (`*.o`), but it doesn't link them into a program). Presumably you meant for the `p1` rule to be `gcc -o p1 main.o insertNode.o`.

Comment: Do you want Makr to *execute* `p1`?

Comment: Should I have gcc -c main.c input.txt output.txt then? I'm sorry I've been at this for days and can't figure it out

Comment: Make should create the file p1, then p1 is executed with the arguments

Comment: Change the `p1` rule in your `Makefile` to `gcc -o p1 main.o insertNode.o`. Then you can do `make p1` which will create a program named `p1`. Then you can run it as `./p1 inputfile.txt outputfile.txt`.

Comment: The line `#include "functions.h"` is in which file(s)?

Comment: The issue that I am finding is that I can't access the text files when I am in main.c. Basically, I try and open the inputfile in main, but I cant access it because of the the fact that it isn't in the argv[] arrray

Comment: if you want to have extra code generated for profiling, then the `-p` parameter must be in all the files to be profiled, during compiling, and be in the linker command.  the posted makefile does not do that.

Answer (score 4):

the following makefile should perform as you are wanting.

```
OBJS := main.o insertNode.o
SRCS := main.c insertNode.c
HDRS := functions.h

.PHONY: all
all: p1 $(SRCS)

%.o:%.c 
<tab>gcc -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ -I.

p1: #(OBJS)
<tab>gcc  $(OBJS) -o $@ $(LFLAGS)
```

to pass in command line arguments to the makefile, use

```
make -f makefile  -Dparm=value
```

Then inside the makefile, the `parm` can be referenced by: `$(parm)` and its' contents will be `value`

to type in

```
p1 inputfile.txt outputfile.txt
```

the main.c file needs to have something similar to:

```
...

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{

    if( 3 != argc )
    { // then invalid number of parameters
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <inputFileName> <outputFileName>\n". argv[0] );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE )
    }

    // implied else, correct number of command line parameters

    // the input file name is pointed to by `argv[1]`
    // the output file name is pointed to by `argv[2]`
```

Comment: Upvoted for the awesome effort of answering this ;).